# Move function outside class definition

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to enhance the readability of my library which features a matrix class. In particular I want users to get a direct overview when looking at the class definition. Therefore I am moving the actual functions outside of the definition. However, *I appear to be unsuccessful for the copy constructor*. In particular I don't succeed to define the templates correctly.

A minimal example (featuring the functions outside the class definition) is the following:

```
#include <vector>

template<class X>
class matrix
{
private:
  std::vector<X> m_data;

public:
  matrix(){};
  matrix(size_t n);
  X& operator[](size_t i);
  size_t size();

  template<\
    typename U,typename V=X,\
    typename=typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<X,U>::value>::type\
  >
  operator matrix<U> ()
  {
    matrix<U> out(size());

    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < size() ; ++i )
      out[i] = static_cast<U>( m_data[i] );

    return out;
  }

};

template<class X>
matrix<X>::matrix(size_t n)
{
  m_data.resize(n);
}

template<class X>
X& matrix<X>::operator[](size_t i)
{
  return m_data[i];
}

template<class X>
size_t matrix<X>::size()
{
  return m_data.size();
}

int main()
{
  matrix<double> A(3);

  matrix<int> B = A;
}
```

Comment: What's with all the `\\` characters?

Comment: where is the copy constructor ? I see only a conversion operator template there ...

Comment: You are right of course....!

Comment: ...uhm, wait, I already answered but maybe this should be marked as duplicate, isn't it ? but strangely I cannot find any at first sight ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question refers to the conversion operator template ( you only have the implicit copy costructor there ), the syntax to move out a member template requires the specification of both *template-parameters* ( class first, without defaults ), hence:

```
template<class X>
template<typename U,typename V,typename E>
matrix<X>::operator matrix<U> ()
{
  //...
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!